# Is this a safe way to parse out HTML tag attributes?

Tags: c#, html, parsing, regex

I needed a super simple parser to get HTML attributes and their values. I didn’t want to load a big library or anything so I made this.

I realize I am making assumptions here, mainly:

- Attribute values will be surrounded with either single or double
  quotes.
- The input string will end with `>` or `/>`.

Besides those assumptions are there any other glaring issues here?

```
Dictionary<string, string> HTMLAttributes(string tag)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> attr = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    MatchCollection matches = 
        Regex.Matches(tag, @"([^\t\n\f \/>""'=]+)(?:=)('.*?'|"".*?"")(?:\s|\/>|\>)");

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        attr.Add(match.Groups[1].Value,
            match.Groups[2].Value.Substring(1, match.Groups[2].Value.Length - 2)
            );
    }

    return attr;
}
```

Running:

```
HTMLAttributes("<body class=\" something \" hello='world' />");
```

Returns:

```
{
    class: " something ",
    hello: "world"
}
```

Sample:

http://ideone.com/ZBaBhB

Comment: “I didn't want to load a big library” Are you sure that's more work than an unreadable line-long regex that you're not sure actually works correctly?

Comment: My concern wasn't my work load but my web app having to load a big library for 1 simple operation.

Comment: Why does that concern you? Are you worried about the small time it takes to load a library (which is done once when the app starts)? Or about the small amount of memory it will require? Both sound like premature optimizations to me. Or do you have another reason?

Comment: It is overkill to load a library for a single function.

Comment: It's not if that function is something that's actually quite complicated like HTML parsing. [You can't parse HTML with regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/41071)

Comment: If that's such a big concern you should probably be looking at something like c++ instead of any of the .net languages.

Comment: Maintaining libraries is often more difficult than maintaining a small piece of code. When the platform changes, and the library has not been updated, you are stuck. The argument can go the other way as well. When parsing requirements change, one can simply update the library and be done. In my experience, the problems happen more than the benefits, so I agree with OP in this case, but for maintenance reasons, not performance reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Whitespace around `=` is allowed, your regex won't handle that.
2. Characters in HTML can be encoded, some characters (like `&`) have to be encoded. For example `name="AT&amp;T"` should return that the value of `name` is `AT&T`.